how to add max. length to anaylze-schema in mongodb?
I'm using MongoDB 4.4.8, installed the snippet alayze-schema and could analyze the coll.
I have the 4 columns: index, attribute, percentage, type.
Is there a way to add one more column: max. length to this?
